# Como fazer o cálculo de quantas semanas tem um determinado mês com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data, calendario

Estou criando um calendário "na mão".

Sei que vocês vão dizer que existem várias libs que já montam o calendário todo, só que no meu projeto não pode ter libs externas além do AngularJS 1.5.8, ou seja não posso usar nenhuma lib que faça isso automaticamente pra mim.

Segue abaixo o código que tentei fazer:

```
var data = new Date();
var dias = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
verificaBissexto(dias);
var num_semanas = Math.floor((dias[mes] + data.getDay()) / 7);
```

Tenho essa variável `dias` que guarda a quantidade de dias de cada mês.

Se eu dividir por 7 o mês de fevereiro desse ano fica com 3 semanas, o que não é real. Tenho uma função que verifica se o ano é bissexto, se o ano for bissexto ele troca os valores por `dias = [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]`, mesmo assim ainda dá problema.

Tentei fazendo a divisão por 5, o mês de fevereiro de 2019 fica bom só que bagunça o fevereiro de 2020.

Essa variável `mes` que está indicando o índice do array está sendo passada por parâmetro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Levando em conta que uma semana tem 7 dias e 4 semanas são 28 dias, então todos os meses possuem 4 semanas, **mais** um determinado número X de dias, sendo que "X" pode ser zero (para fevereiro), 1 (para fevereiro em anos bissextos), 2 (para meses com 30 dias) ou 3 (para meses com 31 dias).

Tudo bem, *tecnicamente* [um mês com 31 dias possui 4,428571428571428... semanas](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=31%20%2F%207&wal=header), mas como você está arredondando para baixo com [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor), então todos os meses deverão ter 4 semanas. Em tese não há o que calcular...

Mesmo que fosse para calcular, não entendi para que somar o valor de `data.getDay()`, já que [segundo a documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay#Return_value) este método retorna um valor de `0` a `6` (0 para domingo, 1 para segunda-feira, etc). E você está usando a data atual (`new Date()`), ou seja, a cada dia que você rodar este código, terá um resultado diferente.

---

Como você quer montar um calendário, *provavelmente* o objetivo é saber quantas linhas serão necessárias para exibir o mês. E isso depende de mais fatores do que simplesmente o número de semanas.

A maioria dos calendários - pelo menos no Brasil - usa o domingo como o primeiro dia da semana, mas há calendários que colocam a [segunda-feira em primeiro](https://www.vectorstock.com/royalty-free-vector/2019-compact-grid-pocket-calendar-first-day-monday-vector-20584045), e já vi bibliotecas em era possível escolher qualquer dia da semana como o primeiro dia. Mas vamos assumir que é domingo, para simplificar.

Neste caso, o calendário de janeiro de 2016 ocuparia 6 linhas (mesmo que o mês não tenha 6 semanas):

```
    Janeiro 2016      
Do Se Te Qu Qu Se Sá  
                1  2  <-- primeira linha
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9  <-- segunda linha  
10 11 12 13 14 15 16  <-- terceira linha  
17 18 19 20 21 22 23  <-- quarta linha  
24 25 26 27 28 29 30  <-- quinta linha  
31                    <-- sexta linha
```

Tudo porque o mês começa em uma sexta, e isso faz com que o dia 31 fique sozinho na sexta linha. Há calendários, principalmente os impressos, que costumam colocar "24/31" no mesmo espaço, mas em calendários *online* tenho notado que a maioria exibe em 6 linhas mesmo.

Já fevereiro de 2015 ocuparia apenas 4 linhas:

```
   Fevereiro 2015     
Do Se Te Qu Qu Se Sá  
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  <-- primeira linha  
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14  <-- segunda linha  
15 16 17 18 19 20 21  <-- terceira linha  
22 23 24 25 26 27 28  <-- quarta linha
```

Neste caso, a quantidade de linhas é igual à quantidade de semanas (quatro). Mas em fevereiro de 2017, mesmo com o mês tendo 28 dias (e portanto a mesma quantidade de semanas), o calendário precisa de 5 linhas:

```
   Fevereiro 2017     
Do Se Te Qu Qu Se Sá  
          1  2  3  4  <-- primeira linha  
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11  <-- segunda linha  
12 13 14 15 16 17 18  <-- terceira linha  
19 20 21 22 23 24 25  <-- quarta linha  
26 27 28              <-- quinta linha
```

Por isso, eu acho que na verdade você não quer a quantidade de semanas, já que todos os meses têm entre 4 e 4,4 semanas, que arredondando para baixo, sempre será 4.

O que você provavelmente está querendo é a quantidade de linhas que serão necessárias no calendário, para mostrar todos os dias de determinado mês. Sendo assim, vamos ver como calcular isso, considerando que o primeiro dia da semana é domingo.

O único caso em que apenas 4 linhas são necessárias é quando o mês tem 28 dias (fevereiro em anos não-bissextos) **e** o primeiro dia do mês é domingo (conforme já visto no exemplo acima, com fevereiro de 2015).

Para verificar isso, bastaria criar uma data no dia 1 do referido mês, verificar se é fevereiro, se é ano bissexto (para saber se tem 28 ou 29 dias) e se o dia é domingo:

```js
// https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ano_bissexto#Calend%C3%A1rio_Gregoriano
// ano bissexto é divisível por 4
// mas se for múltiplo de 100, só é bissexto se for divisível por 400
function bissexto(ano) {
    return ! ((ano % 4) || (!(ano % 100) && (ano % 400)));
}

data.setDate(1); // mudar para dia 1
data.setMonth(mes);
data.setFullYear(ano);
if (data.getDay() == 0 && ! bissexto(data.getFullYear())) {
    // é domingo e ano não é bissexto, vai precisar de 4 linhas no calendário
}
```

Lembrando que o valor passado para `setMonth` deve ser entre 0 e 11 (0 para janeiro, 1 para fevereiro, etc).

Se o mês tiver mais que 28 dias, então sempre precisará de no mínimo 5 linhas. Mas podemos ver apenas os casos em que precisa de 6, já que são em menor número e é mais fácil verificar.

Se o mês tem 30 dias, só será necessária a sexta linha se o primeiro dia for um sábado, como em junho de 2019:

```
     Junho 2019       
Do Se Te Qu Qu Se Sá  
                   1  
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15  
16 17 18 19 20 21 22  
23 24 25 26 27 28 29  
30
```

Repare que se o dia 1 for qualquer outro dia da semana que não o sábado, o dia 30 estará na quinta linha. Ou seja, se o mês tiver 30 dias (e você já sabe verificar isso, por isso não repetirei o código), basta verificar se o valor de `data.getDay()` é 6 (sábado). Se for, serão necessárias 6 linhas, senão apenas 5 bastam.

Já se o mês tem 31 dias, a sexta linha só será necessária se o dia 1 for sexta ou sábado (ou seja, se `getDay()` retorna 5 ou 6). Já vimos um exemplo acima, com janeiro de 2016.

E quando o mês tem 29 dias, nunca precisará de 6 linhas. Veja, por exemplo, fevereiro de 2020:

```
   Fevereiro 2020     
Do Se Te Qu Qu Se Sá  
                   1  
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15  
16 17 18 19 20 21 22  
23 24 25 26 27 28 29
```

Não importa em que dia da semana o mês comece, sempre serão necessárias 5 linhas para exibir o mês.

Resumindo, para um calendário em que o primeiro dia da semana é domingo:

- mês com 28 dias:

  - se primeiro dia do mês é domingo, 4 linhas
  - senão, 5 linhas
- mês com 30 dias:

  - se primeiro dia do mês é sábado, 6 linhas
  - senão, 5 linhas
- mês com 31 dias:

  - se primeiro dia do mês é sexta ou sábado, 6 linhas
  - senão, 5 linhas
- todos os outros casos, 5 linhas

Como não ficou claro como você está montando o calendário (provavelmente é uma tabela, mas enfim, não vou tentar adivinhar), não vou sugerir nenhum código adicional.

Comment: obrigado, ajudou sim, postarei o resultado aqui quando ele estiver pronto, muito obrigado por te dedicado seu tempo pra me ajudar.